# Calling two functions within another function in Gatling is not working

Tags: scala, gatling, scala-gatling

I am trying to execute multiple HTTP calls within one function

Main:

```
def requestChain: ChainBuilder = {
    feed(feeder(dataSource))
    .exec(cleanTransactions("Revoke Transaction"))
  }
```

Now within this method, I am calling 2 other methods which do different http calls. the first call saves the result (Array)in a getLicensesForDevice_TA session variable. When iterating through variable, I am trying to Make another http call based on the elements in the Array. However, it seems that the second call (revokeLicense) for some reason is not executed (The problem does not have to do with the If statement, I already checked that). When calling revokeLicense direkt in the requestChain, it is executed correctly.

```
private def cleanTransactions(methodeName:String, device:String, returnCode:Integer ): ChainBuilder = {
    exec(getLicensesForDevice(methodeName, device, 200))
      .foreach("${getLicensesForDevice_TA}", "deleteLicensesForDevice_TA") {
        exec(session => {
          val gatlingTransactionID = session("deleteLicensesForDevice_TA").as[String].trim
          session.set("gatlingTransactionID", gatlingTransactionID)
        })
        if ("${gatlingTransactionID}".contains("TestTA")){
          exec(revokeLicense(methodeName,"${gatlingTransactionID}",204,false))
        }else{
          exec(session => {
            println("No TA will be executed: ${gatlingTransactionID}" )
            session
          })
        }
      }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

That can't work. As explained in [Gatling's documentation](https://gatling.io/docs/current/general/scenario/#exec), you can't use Gatling DSL inside Scala functions. Gatling DSL methods are just builders that build components once at boot time.

> Gatling DSL components are immutable ActionBuilder(s) that have to be chained altogether and are only built once on startup. The results is a workflow chain of Action(s). These builders don’t do anything by themselves, they don’t trigger any side effect, they are just definitions. As a result, creating such DSL components at runtime in functions is completely meaningless. If you want conditional paths in your execution flow, use the proper DSL components (doIf, randomSwitch, etc)